# How to assign same dynamic id to dom element even after reload in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying assign image url to dom elementid something like this

document.getElementById("w1").src='url'+k+'.jpg';

where value of "k" changes with user click.

The problem is when I refresh page the value of "K" changes to initail value  and it starts from first image.

Is there anyway to assign same id after reload of webpage

Thanks

Comment: use jquery. and if the element are used several times don't use `id`, use `class`. show some sample code here. we'll help you more and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put `k` in the hash of your url:

```
window.location.hash = k;
```

Then when you refresh the page, grab it back again:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        k = parseInt(window.location.hash.split("#")[1]);
        //or remove "parseInt()" if it's not a number
    }
}
```